# Can you have objective c enum same values?

Tags: objective-c

I'm a beginner in Objective C. I've encountered the following typedef enum in Apple docs.

```
    typedef enum NSUnderlineStyle : NSInteger {
   NSUnderlineStyleNone = 0x00,
   NSUnderlineStyleSingle = 0x01,
   NSUnderlineStyleThick = 0x02,
   NSUnderlineStyleDouble = 0x09,
   NSUnderlinePatternSolid = 0x0000,

   NSUnderlinePatternDot = 0x0100,
   NSUnderlinePatternDash = 0x0200,
   NSUnderlinePatternDashDot = 0x0300,
   NSUnderlinePatternDashDotDot = 0x0400,
   NSUnderlineByWord = 0x8000 
} NSUnderlineStyle;
```

Aren't the values for 
NSUnderlineStyleNone = 0x00,
NSUnderlinePatternSolid = 0x0000,

the same hex 0? How is it possible to differentiate the two values?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Apple included them in the same `enum` definition, there are 3 distinct sets of values being defined.  The first is line style, the second is pattern, and one is an option (`ByWord`).

When you define your options, you choose from at most one value from each set, and you OR them together.  By defining a style and a pattern with the same value, it simply means that the default, as defined by bit 0 in the result, will be no underline, but if a style is chosen, the default pattern will be a solid line.

Comment: Thank you @avi, is this grouping some kind of official convention I missed (like prefexing setters with set...)? If so what's the best place to look it all up before annoying people with basic questions? Or is this something you just figured out.

Comment: @Avi, Given a number representing an appropriately combined underline style, is it possible to determine exactly what it is?

Comment: You can test individual bits by ANDing the combined value with the individual enum values.  e.g. if you have the value 0x101, you can determine that it's `NSUnderlinePatternDot` by `0x101 & NSUnderlinePatternDot` and that it's `NSUnderlineStyleSingle` by `0x101 & NSUnderlineStyleSingle`.  Obviously you have to test all the possible values and keep track of which ones match.